# Is there a solution to the FireDAC CopyDataSet and CopyRecord memory loss?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, firedac, copydataset

I have written an application that migrates a series of Paradox tables to a PostgreSQL database. Unfortunately, when importing the data from the Paradox table to the PostgreSQL table, memory consumption increases, and for one of the larger tables (1 million records), the importation crashes with an “out of memory” exception. This crash occurs both when I import the data using CopyDataSet for the table as a whole, as well as when I use CopyRecord to import the data record-by-record.

I’ve been experimenting to learn the source of this memory leak. Originally I thought that the use of the FireDAC ODBC driver was the source. Or more specifically, I thought that the Microsoft ODBC driver was the source. In order to test this, I tried importing from a very large PostgreSQL table into another PostgreSQL table, using the native FireDAC Postgres driver. But the memory leak persisted.

I am opening the source table using a Unidirectional cursor (FetchOptions.Unidirectional := True), which the documentation states will discard records that have already been processed in a forward scan, but the leak persisted. In all cases, I was using an FDQuery. I tried to use an FDTable with its Live Data Windows (LDW) mode enabled, but there is an incompatibility between the Microsoft ODBC driver and the FDTable, so that was not an option.

Here is the basic code that I am using for this test:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM sourcetab;';
FDQuery1.FetchOptions.Unidirectional := True;
FDQuery1.FetchOptions.Mode := fmOnDemand;
FDQuery1.Open();
FDQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM destinationtab WHERE False;';
FDQuery2.Open;
try
  while not FDQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    FDQuery2.Append;
    FDQuery2.CopyRecord( FDQuery1 );
    FDQuery2.Post;
    FDQuery1.Next;
  end;
finally
  FDQuery1.Close;
  FDQuery2.Close;
  ShowMessage( 'Done' );
end;
```

What I ended up doing is to closing, and re-opening the destination table every 1 thousand appends. Closing the destination table stops the linear increase in memory usage. Now the while loop looks like this:

```
while not FDQuery1.Eof do
begin
  FDQuery2.Append;
  FDQuery2.CopyRecord( FDQuery1 );
  FDQuery2.Post;
  if (FDQuery1.RecNo mod  1000) = 0 then
  begin
    FDQuery2.Close;
    FDQuery2.Open;
  end;
  FDQuery1.Next;
end;
```

I tried many other configurations of the FDQueries only to have the same leaky results.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior, and does anyone know of a solution that has less overhead than the closing and re-opening of the destination query?

I am monitoring memory usage using the Task Manager. Once the memory usage approaches 2 GB, the program crashes. Properly closing the destination dataset releases a large amount of memory.

OS: Windows 10 64-bit, Platform: Delphi Rio 10.3.3, Database: PostgreSQL 11, Target platform: 32-bit (no 64-bit Paradox ODBC driver)

Comment: Sorry for a possibly silly query, but when you say "stops the linear increase in memory usage", how are you measuring the memory usage increase?

Comment: Are you sure it is a leak? Do you get a report when enabling ReportmemoryLeaksOnShutdown?

Comment: To answer the first question, I am monitoring memory usage using the Task Manager. Once the memory usage approached 2 GB, the program crashes. As for a "true" memory leak, neither ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown nor Deleaker report a memory leak. However, the runaway memory usage is indicative of some lack of proper memory management. Closing the target dataset and then re-opening it again at least keeps the memory usage from continuing to rise. Properly closing the target dataset releases the memory. I am not sure that ReportMemoryLeakOnShutdown would report a leak after a crash.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that info could usefully be included in your q.

Comment: Could be heap fragmentation then. Are you using the design time component or do you create the FDQueries at runtime?

Comment: Anyway I don't use Firedac as it is a hopeless pile of sh*t. I would use devart or zeos in your case...

Comment: whosrdaddy: I've tested it both ways with the same result.

Comment: This way you did (FDQuery2.Close/Open) is right, FDQuery store all records on memory, so you need to clear them from memory, this way.is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered something similar while using the same approach as you including the close/open workaround.

The reason for the memory increase (it is no memory leak!) is the amount of appended records to the target query internal record buffer. While *Unidirectional* helps limiting the memory of the source query, it cannot stop the target query to add record after record increasing the memory with each. As the target query only appends records, which will never be used or searched for, this is totally wasted.

You can keep your workaround with close and open, which is perfectly working for me, too.

As an alternative you can use a simple INSERT query, which needs some more coding to get the source fields into the target parameters, though.

**Edit:** Actually, the query could know that if can free all previous records in the buffer after *Append* and *Post* when *Unidirectional* is True, but as that is a *FetchOption* it may not be thought of during *Post*.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling [ApplyUpdates](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates) for the changes that you have made to be actually synced with the database provider. Until you do this all the changes are stored in internal record buffer on the client side.And as far as I know `ApplyUpdates` is called just before closing the database connection in order to sync up pending data with the database itself.

Comment: @SilverWarior, ApplyUpdates is only used when CachedUpdates is True. BTW, your link is for TClientDataSet, not for TFDQuery.